# How can I grey out/disable certain fields?

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using a Webform module for my multi page form. I would like certain form elements to be greyed out/disabled if an answer to one of the questions is "Yes" (dropdown list).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Webform 3.x, you're probably looking for the [Webform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module.  If you're using 4.x, conditionals support is built in.

Adding conditionals to your webform will allow you to show or hide webform fields based on answers to other fields.  Using the above module or built-in support in 4.x, you could completely hide a certain field if the answer to another field was "Yes."